# What is wrong with this test class? It is not covering, any suggestions? Thanks,

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

```
@isTest
public class PropRentTotalSumTEST {
    @isTest
    static void testFeeCalculation() {



        Property__c prop = new Property__c();
        prop.Name = 'Test';
        prop.Monthly_Rate__c = 0;

        insert prop;

        List<Fee__c> fees = new List<Fee__c>();
        Fee__c fees1=new Fee__c();
        fees1.Name = 'Realtor';
        fees1.Cost__c = 1000;
        fees1.Property__c = prop.Id;

        Fee__c fees2=new Fee__c();
        fees2.Name = 'Lawyer';
        fees2.Cost__c = 2000;
        fees2.Property__c = prop.Id;
        fees.add(fees1);
        fees.add(fees2);

        Test.startTest();

    insert fees;
    delete fees;

        Test.stopTest();

    Property__c propsProperty = [SELECT Monthly_Rate__c FROM Property__c WHERE Id =: prop.Id];

        System.assertEquals(0, propsProperty.Monthly_Rate__c);

    }
}
```

```
public with sharing class PropRentTotalSum {
    public static void RentTotal(List<Fee__c> fees) {

        List<Id> ids = new List<Id>();
        List<Property__c> properties = new List<Property__c>();
        for (Fee__c fee : fees) {
            ids.add(fee.Property__c);
        }
        for (Property__c property : [
                SELECT Id,Monthly_Rate__c, (SELECT Id, Cost__c FROM Fees__r)
                FROM Property__c
                WHERE Id = :ids
        ]) {
            Decimal sum = 0;
            for (Fee__c fee1 : property.Fees__r) {
                sum = sum + fee1.Cost__c;
            }
            property.Monthly_Rate__c = sum;
            properties.add(property);
        }
        try {
            update properties ;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception :' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add  the class and Test class  completely?

Comment: the post updated, thanks.

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call class and respected method name

Please find below:In Your Test class:

```
   PropRentTotalSum.RentTotal(fees); //Pass List of fees
```

In your test class: dont delete fess

```
               delete fees;
```

After insert why you are deleting fees any specific reason??

Comment: Because of the after trigger. Now I put the list you suggested and had to try catch all inserts, but still the test coverage is only 52%. What else is needed to be done to get 100%?

Comment: In question,, you havent mentioned that its after trigger..just update the  trigger.. automatically this class will cover ..can you please add after trigger code